# how to use knpPaginatorBundle with rest api?

Tags: symfony, knppaginator

**I try to use**

public function listeleAction(Request $request)
    { 
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

```
    $yasam_list=$em->getRepository("VanBundle:Yasam")->findAll();

    if (count($yasam_list)>0)
    {
    $yanit=array();
    foreach ($yasam_list as $meta)
    {
        $new_yasam=array();
        $new_yasam['id']=$meta->getId();
        $new_yasam['adi']=$meta->getAdi();
        $new_yasam['adres']=$meta->getAdres();
        $new_yasam['kategori_id']=$meta->getKategori()->getAdi();
        array_push($yanit,$new_yasam);
    }
        $paginator=$this->get('knp_paginator');

        $result= $paginator->paginate(
            $yanit,
            $request->query->getInt('page',1),
            $request->query->getInt('limit',10)
        );

    }else{
        $yanit["success"] = 0;
  $response["message"] = "Bu kategoriye en kısa sürede veri eklenecektir. ";
    }

    $response=new Response(json_encode(array('yasamlar' =>$result),JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
    $response->headers->set('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    return $response;
}
```

**my json output**

```
{
"yasamlar": {}
}
```

How can I solve this? thanks all

Comment: Why do not you use the pagination on the doctrine query?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**I solved**

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        //listelenecek bütün Yasam
        $yasam_list=$em->getRepository("VanBundle:Yasam")->findAll();



        $pager=$this->get('knp_paginator');
        $paginated=$pager->paginate($yasam_list,$request->query->getInt('page',1), $request->query->getInt('limit',10));

        $factory=new KnpPaginatorFactory();
        $collection=$factory->createRepresentation($paginated,new Configuration\Route('yasamjson_index'),array()); 

        $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
        $data = $serializer->serialize([
            'meta' => $collection,
            'data' => $paginated->getItems()
        ], 'json');


       return new Response($data);

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Before coming to pagination, few suggestions :

- Use `KnpPaginatorBundle` along with doctrine query builder. Running full query and doing pagination from the result doesn't help in improvising performance.
- For REST API, you can use [FosRestBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html). With few configuration you don't have to do `json_encode`, setup `Content-Type` or `Status Code`.
- If you don't want to use [FosRestBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html). Explore and try to use `JsonResponse` in return instead of `Response`.

Now, regarding passing `KnpPagination` info to API :

If you are using [FosRestBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html), you can use [JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle) which will help you parse the Entity information to `JSON` for API responses. You can further choose which property to be exposed. The pagination data will be automatically parsed.

Else, you just have to iterate through KNPPaginator `$result` object, which you get form doctrine query builder, and send pagination and data separately to `JsonResponse`.

Let me know if you need code snippet.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i don't use FosRestBundle